# What is a vector of effects?

Tags: latent-class, mixed-type-data

The journal article in question is [this article](http://people.ucalgary.ca/~adeleon/CJS_gmdm.pdf) (*General mixed-data model: extension of general location and grouped continuous models*, de Leon and Carriere), on p. 535 (or, based on the PDF file, p. 3).

Starting at the third full paragraph (emphasis mine),

> To avoid overparametrizing the model, state $S$ is fixed as a reference state, and $\boldsymbol{\mu}_s$ and $\boldsymbol{\mu}^{*}_s$ ($s = 1, \dots, S-1$) are defined as $\boldsymbol{\mu}_s = \boldsymbol{\xi} + \boldsymbol{\xi}_s$ and $\boldsymbol{\mu}_s^{*} = \boldsymbol{\xi}^{*} + \boldsymbol{\xi}_s^*$, where $\boldsymbol{\xi}$ and $\boldsymbol{\xi}^{*}$ are the means of $\mathbf{y}$ and $\mathbf{y}^{*}$, respectively, for state $S$, and $\boldsymbol{\xi}_s$ and $\boldsymbol{\xi}_s^*$ are the **effects of state $s = 1, \dots, S-1$ relative to that of state $S$**.

What are these "effects" supposed to be? I'm familiar with the terminology of a "mixed effects" model, but I'm not sure at all what these "effects" here are.

Comment: Doesn't the relationship $\xi_s = \mu_s  - \xi$ fully answer this question?

Comment: @whuber OH, that's what it's talking about. Thanks. -_- /(should've seen that)